# Use Gmail to send/receive email with custom domain through Outlook/Office 365 servers

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, office365

Here is the desired outcome:

1. All email tasks completed in Gmail (never load Outlook.com)
2. Email is on a **custom domain** e.g. joe@bloggs.com
3. Emails are actually sent/received via Outlook's SMTP/IMAP servers
4. Emails are **properly authenticated** (DKIM, SPF and TLS)

Is it possible?

Why? I pay for Office 365 (and hence its Outlook servers – being the reason for point 3). But I hate Outlook and Free Gmail is the client I want to use (being the reason for point 1).

However, sending with a custom domain in Free Gmail can lead to:

- Deliverability issues as not properly authenticated
- Often shows up for recipients as "sent by joe@**gmail.com** on behalf of joe@**bloggs.com**"

So, is it possible to connect my custom domain to Office 365/Outlook to take advantage of professional email delivery, while still using Gmail entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this feature has existed for quite a few years. When adding new addresess through Gmail's "Send mail as", Gmail has long ago started asking to enter the relay SMTP server's information, and in fact now it seems to be [the only option remaining.](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2014/08/external-addresses-no-longer-use-gmail.html)

So it should be enough to remove and re-add your address and fill in the correct details.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I think this only means I can _send_ via that domain. How can I also ensure I _receive_ on it within free Gmail?

Comment: Yes, as your main complaint was about the send feature not working properly, I assumed you already have the receive feature (which is completely separate) working fine

Comment: Ah, sorry. No, sending seems easy enough – but I'm after a setup where I can receive in Gmail too.